# Swift Methods Executing Out of Order as Program is Not Waiting for URLSession.shared.dataTask to Finish

Tags: ios, json, swift, decodable

I am trying to write an app where data is retrieved from an API and subsequently shows up in the view of an app.   The issue is when I run my code, the setupViews() where views are set up is always running before the JSON data is retrieved even though I called it after the getJson() function.  The getJson() function is running first but it is stopping at the  " URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: the_urlObj) {(data, _,error) in " and skipping over the rest of the function and then executing all of the remaining functions first before the program returns to it.   How do I get the full getJson() function to execute before the setupViews() function is called?

I've noticed that the URLSession.shared.dataTask line is where the code in the getJson() function is stopping. It returns to the remainder of that code after the setupViews() function is already executed. I tried calling self.setupViews() in the getJson() block after the  URLSession.shared.dataTask line, but the view still shows up without the data.

> // viewDidLoad function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getJson()
    setupViews()
}
```

> //getJson function

```
func getJson(){
    let jsonString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=brooklyn,us&APPID=f942c97cab0e663a9a4882e6c3f0db1e"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data,response,err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
    do {

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        let weatherData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)
        print("temperature: ", weatherData.main.temp)
        // self.todays_weather.text = String("\(temperature)")
        temperature = Int(weatherData.main.temp)
        temperature = (temperature * 9/5)-459

    }
    catch {
        print(err)
        print(response)
    }

}.resume()
```

}

> //setup views function

```
func setupViews(){
    self.view.addSubview(todays_weather)
    todays_weather.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 140).isActive = true
    todays_weather.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
    todays_weather.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    todays_weather.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 120).isActive = true

    self.view.addSubview(weather_button)
    weather_button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 240).isActive = true
    weather_button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
    weather_button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    weather_button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -90).isActive = true
```

}

```
let todays_weather : UITextField = {
    let weather = UITextField()
    weather.textColor = UIColor.black
    weather.textAlignment = .center
    weather.text = String("\(temperature)")
    weather.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:32)
    weather.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return weather
}()
```

The code runs fine, but the text field in the view is displayed as 0 and not the temperature retrieved by JSON, since setupViews() is executing before the JSON data is finished being retrieved since the getJson() functions stop at URLSession.shared.dataTask.

I am getting this notice in the console though:
2019-07-29 11:44:01.060026-0400 daily_tips[46459:8017625] This application is modifying the AutoLayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You’re not showing us how `getJson` is updating the UI (perhaps you have an observer on `temperature`?). But the key issue is that the `dataTask` runs its completion handlers on the `URLSession` queue (which by default is a background serial queue). So, if you’re updating model objects and/or UI in the `dataTask` completion handler, you should dispatch those updates back to the main queue via `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }`.

Comment: You do not "wait". Data task function is asynchronous. Networking is asynchronous. Asynchronous code _does_ execute "out of order". That is what asynchronous _means_.

Comment: http://www.programmingios.net/what-asynchronous-means/

Comment: Unrelated, I’m inferring that `temperature` is an `Int`. You should do your conversion using floating point types and only then convert the final result into an integer. If you check your existing conversion with a calculator, you’re likely going to see your algorithm is doing some rounding. (Even then, the algorithm is suspicious: What units are you attempting to convert between?)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow! What's going on for you is that the JSON fetch happens asynchronously but you call `setupViews()` right after calling `getJson()`.

A good solution to this is to add a completion handler to the `getJson()` call.

```
func getJson(completionHandler: () -> ()){
    let jsonString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=brooklyn,us&APPID=f942c97cab0e663a9a4882e6c3f0db1e"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data,response,err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {

            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
            decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
            let weatherData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)
            print("temperature: ", weatherData.main.temp)
            // self.todays_weather.text = String("\(temperature)")
            temperature = Int(weatherData.main.temp)
            temperature = (temperature * 9/5)-459
            completionHandler()
        }
        catch {
            print(err)
            print(response)
        }

    }.resume()
}
```

Then call setupViews() in the completionHandler:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getJson { [weak self] in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.setupViews()
        }
    }
}
```

I'd recommend doing a search for "ios asynchronous programming" and a search for "ios completion handlers" to learn more. There's lots of great info out there and I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! New to IOS and this helped.

Comment: @aport550, if this solved your issue, hit that check mark next to Nate's answer to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

Straightforward solution without completion handler, put `setupViews()` in the completion handler of `dataTask`.

And with the parameter `units=imperial` in the openweathermap URL you get all degrees in Fahrenheit.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getJson()
}

func getJson(){
    let jsonString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=brooklyn,us&units=imperial&APPID=f942c97cab0e663a9a4882e6c3f0db1e"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonString) else { return }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [unowned self] data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else { print(error!); return }
    do {

        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        let weatherData = try decoder.decode(WeatherData.self, from: data)
        print("temperature: ", weatherData.main.temp)
        // self.todays_weather.text = String("\(temperature)")
        temperature = Int(weatherData.main.temp)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.setupViews()
        }

    }
    catch {
        print(error)
        print(response)
    }

}.resume()
```